# Appending css to current menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to add css marker to my menus to identify current page and current parent menu as follows:
`http://myweb.com/#about -`  This is a parent menu with children like
`http://myweb.com/about/history -` This is a page with content
`http://myweb.com/about/vision -` This is a page with content

This is the markup

```
<ul id="menu"  class="nav-main">                         
<li><a href="#about">About</a> 
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.myweb.com/about/history">History</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.myweb.com/about/vision">Vision</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a> 
<ul>
<li>.....</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have the below javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("ul#menu.nav-main li a[href='#@Request.Url.LocalPath.Split('/')[1]']").parent("li").addClass("current-menu-item");
</script>
```

This marks the parent menu and all the children menus instead of the desired. that is; marking only the parent menu and the particular page.  For example at  http://myweb.com/about/history page  I want only that and  http://myweb.com/#about parent menu to be marked.  Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Show the rendered HTML, not the server-side code

Comment: thanks I have changed to html markup

Comment: Change your javascript section too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will help you

Jquery:

```
//for example i hardcoded the url below
var url='http://www.myweb.com/parent-info/stuff';
//when you test in live replace above code by below
//var url $(location).attr('href') 
var url_cnt=url.split('/');
if(url_cnt[url_cnt.length-1].length != 0 && url_cnt[url_cnt.length-2].length!=0){
$("#menu a").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(url_cnt[url_cnt.length-1].toLowerCase()) > -1;}).addClass("current-menu-item");
$("#menu a").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(url_cnt[url_cnt.length-2].toLowerCase()) > -1;}).addClass("current-menu-item");
}
```

Here is the latest updated JSFiddle dinn:http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/17/

Comment: Thanks Nandha.  What I need is  when you click to visit a submenu I want currnt- menu-item class to be added to the parent menu and the submenu .

Comment: @Diin try above answer diin,that works same way as you expected.

Comment: it does same as I do not want.  on click of  "history" it  marks "about" and "vision" as well as "history".  What I want is if I select " history" it should mark only" history" and "about"

Comment: @Diin understand dinn, try above code that will help you

Comment: I see that at the point of clicking  it adds the css class but when the page refreshes to the new page from the link the css does not stay

Comment: @Diin when the page refresh you actually binding menu once again so it lost the css, to avoid this use session,store the current details before page refresh and retrieve the details from session and assign to menu after page refresh.

Comment: I do not want to use session

Comment: @Diin try this fiddle dinn,http://jsfiddle.net/jvyLtr82/14/ this will exactly hep you

Comment: thanks this is generally  working  but when at homepage it highlights every menu and submenu

Comment: Thanks that works fine the last thing is if the link has a dash like parent-info/stuff   it does not mark  parent-info with css.  You have done a lot on this already I only hope if you can fix this one too

Comment: can you update the answer with the latest fiddle so that I can mark your answer

Comment: @Diin i tested with parent-info/stuff,it works for me ,if it does not for you, create one fiddle and show me dinn.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the generic solution but try if this can solve your issue.

Try giving id's to your `li`s like below

```
<html>
    <body>

    <ul id="menu"  class="nav-main">                         
            <li id="about"><a href="#about">About</a> 
                <ul>
                    <li id="history"><a href="http://www.myweb.com/about/history">History</a></li>
                    <li id="vision"><a href="http://www.myweb.com/about/vision">Vision</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="contact"><a href="#contact">contact</a> 
            <ul>

            </ul>
            </li>
    </ul>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url=$(location).attr('href');
        alert(url);
        if(url.indexOf("history")>=0)
        {
          ("#about").addClass("current-menu-item");
          ("#history").addClass("current-menu-item");

        }
        else if(url.indexOf("vision")>=0)
        {
          ("#about").addClass("current-menu-item");
          ("#vision").addClass("current-menu-item");
        }
    }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but I have a lot more menus -  about 30 of them and so I need a solution that will be dynamic